# Javascript in <th> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML and I want to put 2 TH, the second one will be to select all the checkboxes of the rows. But when I click nothing happens.

```html
<table id="books" class="m-0" width="100%" style="margin-top:0 !important;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><b>#</b></th>
            <th><b>id</b></th>
            <th><b>Name</b></th>
            <th><b>Status</b></th>
            <th><b>Images</b></th>
            <th><b>Is Extension</b></th>
            <th onclick=javascript:alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!") ><b>Novel</b></th>
            <th><b>Novel</b></th>
            <th><b>Actions</b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><b>#</b></th>
            <th><b>id</b></th>
            <th><b>Name</b></th>
            <th><b>Status</b></th>
            <th><b>Images</b></th>
            <th><b>Is Extension</b></th>
            <th><b>ISBM</b></th>
            <th><b>NOVEL</b></th>
            <th><b>Actions</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

Comment: You need to quote attributes and you do not need to use `javascript:`

Comment: Oh look! An error in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have wrong syntax, use it like this

```
<th onclick="alert('Hello! I am an alert box!!')"><b>Novel</b></th>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<th onclick="alert('Hello! I am an alert box!!');" ><b>Novel</b></th>
```

Answer (score 1):

How your code is rendered by browser:

```
<th onclick="javascript:alert(&quot;Hello!" i="" am="" an="" alert="" box!!")=""><b>Novel</b></th>
```

To fix this, put it in quotes:

```
<th onclick="alert('Hello! I am an alert box!!')"><b>Novel</b></th>
```